# Finding the order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

When we have permutation elements like $b=(12)(234)(1223)$ we can easily say that the order of each cycle is $2$, $3$ and $4$ respectively so the order of $b=\text{lcm}(2,3,4)$.

When we have $C_n$, does that mean the element with the highest order is $n$?

If this is the case then is it the same case for when wanting to find the highest order of elements in say $G=C_{5} \times C_{12} \times C_7$. So the highest order element is simply $\text{lcm}(5,12,7)=420$?

Comment: what group is $C_n$?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat The nth roots of unity

Comment: For a permutation you can say that the order is the lowest common multiple of the lengths of cycles *only if* the cycles are disjoint. A simple counterexample is $(13)(12)=(123)$ which has order $3$, not $2$.

Comment: @egreg So it would be good to make the cycles independent first right?

Comment: @snowman It's *necessary*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $C_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ the highest order for an element is $n$, that is the generator of $C_n$. When you have a product like $G=C_{a_1}\times C_{a_2}\times C_{a_3}\times \dots \times C_{a_m}$, highest order is, as you say, $\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_m)$, so you're right in that case.

One example of an element with this order may be the copy of each generator, $(1_{a_1},1_{a_2},\dots,1_{a_m})$.

Answer (score 4):

The cyclic group indeed has order $n$ because it is the group generated by $\left<x\right>$ where $x$ has order $n$.

However, I think there is a problem with the product of groups because you have to show that it (the product) is isomorphic to a group of order $420$.

Comment: the problem I am doing is: "What is the highest order of element in G? How many elements are there in G of the highest order". I have to first find what the highest order is. So am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't see the problem.